# Linear system of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to solve a coupled linear system like this :

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y $$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x $$

I tried to solve that by making
$$x dx = y dy$$
Integrating I obtain 
$$x^2 - y^2 = C $$
where $C$ is a constant

I think I made some mistake, can any one help me with this?

Comment: Because both of the equations are the same except for x and y "reversed", $\frac{dx}{dt}=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating the first identity yields
$$x''=y'$$
And substituting in the second equation
$$x''=x$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

we have $dx/dt=y$
and $dy/dt=x$
so $d²x/dt²=x$
so $x=exp(t+C)$ where C is a constant

Comment: @ MEKTOUBI: your "solution" is not complete ! The general solution of the equation $x''=x$ is given by: $x(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use Laplace transform. So we have that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{x}'\left(t\right)=\text{y}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{y}'\left(t\right)=\text{x}\left(t\right)
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Take the Laplace transform of both sides:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{s}\cdot\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{x}\left(0\right)=\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)\\
\\
\text{s}\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)=\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So, we also get that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{x}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}\\
\\
\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

So, substitute them into each other:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}+\text{x}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}\\
\\
\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{x}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}+\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}}
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\begin{cases}
\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{s}\cdot\text{x}\left(0\right)+\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}^2-1}\\
\\
\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{s}\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)+\text{x}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}^2-1}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

So, using inverse Laplace transform we get that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{x}\left(t\right)=\text{x}\left(0\right)\cdot\cosh\left(t\right)+\text{y}\left(0\right)\cdot\sinh\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{y}\left(t\right)=\text{y}\left(0\right)\cdot\cosh\left(t\right)+\text{x}\left(0\right)\cdot\sinh\left(t\right)
\end{cases}\tag5
$$